# How to make JSF Flash Cookie HttpOnly and Secure

Tags: jsf, cookies

In our JSF application we can see the below cookies :-

1. oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN
2. oam.Flash.REDIRECT

Can someone please tell how these cookies can be made secure and HttpOnly. I am using tomcat.

thanks

Comment: Hi, Always start by using a search engine https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=httponly+cookies+apache+myfaces, then read and investigate (like stated in [ask]). If you did not find a solution create a question and add references to links you found that did not help. Oh and **ALWAYS** post jsf version and implementation (I suspecet myfaces in your case)

Comment: Yup, one of search results there is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3639

Comment: @BalusC:Was just creating an answer ;-)  edit: Oh you already upvoted ;-)

Comment: Any feedback? You were online just minutes ago...

Comment: Thanks , i tried to google but could not find it. My problem still remains the same. As this is fixed in MyFaces 2.2.4 but i am currently using 2.0.21. Is there any alternate to handle this in code/configuration. TIA

Comment: @BalusC .. i am using MyFaces 2.0.21. So this is not fixed in my version. Can i access this cookie grammatically and set the attributes explicitly, like we do in servlets ?

Comment: Two solutions: update (which is good in multiple ways) and the other is: patch or look at the soucecode. Code of all versions is open source. Download both, compare and fix....

Comment: I have updated my JARs to 2.2.4 my faces. But after that i have started getting INVALID PPR RESPONSE with certain entities.

Comment: Is there some configuration required to overcome this. I have found many ppl reporting the same issue after upgrading the myfaces. But could not find any solution yet. TIA

Comment: @BalusC: This is only about httpOnly. And how about secure flag?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is that it 'just works' in recent MyFaces versions (2.2.4 and up). A very simple search in a search engine helped me finding it.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3639

Comment: This is not THE answer. This is only about httpOnly. And how about secure flag?